# C# / JQuery webservice call gives 500 error

Tags: c#, jquery, asmx

This has got me stumped - I have no idea what the problem is!

This call always returns a 500 error:

Query:

```
$('body').on('click', '.day', function () {
    // a suspect day has been clicked
    if (confirm('Re-index documents received on this day?')) {
        // re-index
        var day = $(this).find('.day_number').text();
        var year = parseInt($('#hidYear').val());
        var month = parseInt($('#hidMonth').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.asmx/ReIndexDay",
            data: JSON.stringify( { Month: month, Year: year, Day: day } ),
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data) {
                var calendarHTML = $(data).find(':first').text();
                // update hidden fields and calendar
                $('#hidYear').val(year);
                $('#hidMonth').val(month);
                $('#divContent').html(calendarHTML);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Re-index the day and return HTML of a calendar table for the month")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string ReIndexDay(int Day, int Month, int Year)
{
    Diagnostic.ReIndex(Day, Month, Year);
    return GetIndexCalendarHTML(Month, Year);
}
```

I'm stuck now so all suggestions appreciated!

[edit]

I got this from the browser - not sure if it's accurate as it might not be reproducing the same thing:

System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/xml; charset=UTF-8. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

[/edit]

Comment: If it's returning an HTTP 500, that indicates your server is throwing an exception somewhere that is uncaught. Are you able to debug your web method?

Comment: Yep sorry - I should have said I've tried debugging the server code but it doesn't seem to get hit at all. Sort of implies there's a problem with the post format, but it all looks ok to me!

Comment: use Fiddler to see what happens. Another thing contentType is xml, dataType also, but you are passing a JSON..

Comment: Plus, I would imagine that your parameters should probably be `int?` to better accomodate binding failures.

Comment: I changed the int parameters to int? with no improvement, although it was a good suggestion! I'm downloading fiddler now.

Comment: It looks like you're passing JSON. Why is the content type:  contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sending JSON, but you have content type set to XML.  Try changing it to this.

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: Dammit - you're right!. Can't believe I missed that. The only issue now is I get an error of "200: OK" which is being caught by the error function instead of the success function. Is there an obvious solution to that?

Comment: The error problem is because I'm saying that I'm dealing with JSON but the response is XML. :$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the content type to:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

instead of XML like you had (as @Zachary said (and I said in a comment :)). You also need to actually send back XML.

Saying:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
```

Doesn't actually encode your string as XML, all it does is set the Content-type header to:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8.
```

*You* actually have to return the XML. It's a bit misleading.

*Edit*: Actually, let me ammend that. It *does* XML *except* when you send a string. You can have it wrap your string in XML by doing this:

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml, XmlSerializeString=true)]

Comment: Thanks aquinas, although I am returning XML ok so no problems. :)

Comment: See my updated answer and see if that helps. I tried reproducing your problem and got the same thing you mentioned when I sent back a non-xml string, as soon as I changed it to XML however, it worked fine.